# Convergence of a sequence of measures of sets implies convergence of the indicator functions.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $\lambda$ be the lebesgue measure on the Borel sets. Suppose $\lambda(A) < \infty$

Is the following true? $\lambda(B_n) \uparrow \lambda (A), B_n \subseteq A \implies 
 I_{B_n} \to I_A$ a.e.

I think it should be true. I cannot apply monotone convergence theorem because that would be the other implication.

I tried rewriting $\lambda(B_n) = \int I_{B_n}d\lambda$ and do something with that but that didn't work either.

Any hints?

Comment: If $B_1\subset B_2\subset B_3\subset ...$ then this is true (a.e.). Otherwise you can have counterexamples.

Comment: Mind providing/referencing a counterexample? Or in the first place, why it is true when you have that chain of inclusions.

Comment: Say $A=[0,1]$, $B_n=[0,1]-[a2^{-k}, (a+1)2^{-k}]$ where $k$ is the biggest integer with $2^k\leq n$ and $a=n-2^k$.

Comment: Thanks. And what about the case where $B_1 \subseteq B_2 \subseteq \dots$?

Comment: @Math_QED that is called the continuity of measure from below (and you could actually use MCT there)

Comment: The continuity of measure from below just implies that $\lambda(\bigcup_n B_n) = \lim_n \lambda(B_n) = \lambda(A)$. How does that help?

Comment: My bad, it actually may not be necessary. Suppose the conclusion weren't true in the nested case. Then $\lambda(A-B) >0$ where $B = \cup B_n$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! Add this to your answer! Why exactly we have $\lambda(A - B) > 0?$ I also managed to show the result using monotone convergence theorem if they are nested.

Comment: Because the question changed (to $A$ being finite measure) @YuDing's example is more appropriate -- I can expand on that

Comment: Oh $\lambda(A-B) >0$ since if $\mathbb{1}_{B_n}$ doesn't converge almost everywhere to $\mathbb{1}_{A}$, then there is a positive-measure-set of nonconvergence.

Comment: Yes, the set $\{x \mid \neg(I_{B_n}(x) \to I_A(x))\}$ must have positive measure. Then still how $\lambda(A -B) > 0$?

Comment: This is because when $B_n$ are nested and contained in $A$, that positive measure set is exactly the same as the set $A-B$. If you integrate $1$ over that set, you get a positive number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $B_n= [n,2n]$ and $A=(-\infty,\infty)$ to get a counterxample in the infinite case.

If you assume $A$ to be finite, construct a counterexample as follows. Let $A=[0,1]$

Step 1: Divide $A$ into halves. $B_1$ will be $[0,1/2]$, then $B_2$ will be $[1/2,1]$. Notice how each has measure 1/2.

Step 2: Divide $A$ into quarters. $B_3$,$B_4$,$B_5$ and $B_6$ will each have measure 3/4 by picking exactly three of these quarters.

Step 3: Divide $A$ into eighths. The next 8 $B_n$'s will be formed by choosing exactly seven of these eighths. These each have measure 7/8.

and so on... The measure of $B_n$ approaches 1. The indicators do not converge, since every point will be 0 infinitely often.